# What is the meaning of "treats" in this case?

Tags: meaning

The main text:

> Addiction ... is a matter of learning that the addictive cue - a game... - **treats** loneliness, disaffection, and distress.

[Source](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xBNGDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&lpg=PT56&dq=%22is%20a%20matter%20of%20learning%20that%20the%20addictive%22&source=bl&ots=hxI38QJe0h&sig=VL6GMwtrqz1encs1leNlQWNNyDU&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiButOzjKvUAhXLCMAKHeTuDMsQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20a%20matter%20of%20learning%20that%20the%20addictive%22&f=false)

Comment: "Treats" is simply the wrong word here, but for the life of me, I can't quite work out what the author meant, or what word should have been used.  Here's the full quote: "Addiction, as it was for Isaac Vaisberg, the Vietnam vets, and Rat No. 34, is a matter of learning that the addictive cue—a game, a place paired with heroin,or a small metal bar — treats loneliness, disaffection, and distress."  Either "Is linked to" or "relieves", perhaps, but I'm guessing.  A case of a garbled original.

Comment: @RobinHamilton It's like saying that aspirin treats a headache.

Comment: @Barmar  But the context seems to suggest that things **associated** with the addiction -- a game, place, or bar -- "treat" the addiction.  This doesn't make sense to me.  Maybe reading the entire four or five pages preceding the paragraph in question might clarify, but I'm not prepared to go that far.  As it stands, we have: "the addictive cue ... treats loneliness [etc.] ..."  It's beyond me how an "addictive cue" can "treat" anything.  How can "going to a place associated with heroin" _treat_ heroin addiction?  I think we're simply being confronted with a sheerly bad piece of writing.

Comment: It's not treating the addiction, it's treating the emotions that are part of the addictive personality. If you're a video game addict, playing a game makes you feel less lonely or distressed. That's what makes them an addict -- they need to perform the activity to relieve these conditions.

Comment: Perhaps, and what you say above makes sense.  But can we derive that simply from the paragraph where the term "treats" appears?  I stand by my point that fundamentally, we're confronted by piece of exceptionally badly-worded prose.

Answer (score 1):

It's this definition from [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/treat)

> Give medical care or attention to; try to heal or cure.

or [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/treat?s=t)

> to deal with (a disease, patient, etc.) in order to relieve or cure.

It's saying that an addict has learned that partaking of the activity relieves those conditions.

Comment: The Barmar's explanation seems reasonable.